# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting the below error while submitting the form.it is saying the value is undefined  while onSubmit is called. The error and the code is pasted below. the complete HTML file is added. I am coding in Angular 8.

```
EmployeeComponent.html:14 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at EmployeeComponent.onSubmit (employee.component.ts:38)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (EmployeeComponent.html:14)
    at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
    at core.js:31837
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:35379)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
```

**HTML Code: EmployeeComponent.html** - Adding the complete HTML code

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col s5">

  <form employeeForm="ngform"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
      <input type="hidden" name="_id" _id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id"/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
           <input type="text"  name="name" #_name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name"> 
          <label>Name: 
              <label class="red-text">*</label>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" name="position" #_position="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.position" >
          <label>position:
              <label class="red-text">*</label>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" name="office" #_office="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.office" >
          <label>Office:
              <label class="red-text">*</label>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" name="salary" #_salary="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._salary" >
          <label>Salary:
              <label class="red-text">*</label>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn btn-custom right"  type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-custom right" (click)="reset(employeeForm)" type="reset" >Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**employee.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
     this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.resetForm(form);
      M.toast({html: 'Saved Successfully!',classess:'rounded'});
    });
  }
}
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  employees: Employee[];
  readonly baseURL='http://localhost:3000/employees';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

postEmployee(emp : Employee){
     return this.http.post(this.baseURL, emp);
}

}
```

Comment: try logging `form` variable in `onSubmit` method, it will print `undefined`

Comment: btw you should use `#employeeForm="ngform"`

Comment: thanks.. it is printing as undefined. and i used '#' but it was throwing an error  so i removed it.

Comment: Can you please post your complete HTML file ?

Comment: @Prince : Added the complete HTML in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments the issue with the code is you need to add # before employeeForm, this is the convention to define a template reference variable.

And the second issue is spelling mistake of ngform. It should be ngForm. Statement should be like:

```
<form #employeeForm="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
```

Please find below the working stackblitz with basic code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmegcq